# How to import one typescript file into another for web, not node.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, web-worker

I'm trying to share code (to prevent copying and pasting it multiple times in multiple files.) between a main index.ts file and a web worker worker.ts file. *This is all being compiled to javascript for the browser.*

As a simplified example, here is my **dependency.ts** that I want to reference code from:

**dependency.ts**

```js
function print_to_console(msg:string) {
    console.log(msg);
}
```

I want to reference that in my main file:

**index.ts**

```js
dependency.print_to_console("Print from main");

var worker = new Worker("worker.js");
worker.postMessage("Print from worker");
```

And from my web worker:

**worker.ts**

```js
async function init_worker() {
    self.onmessage = async event => {
        let msg:string = event.data;
        dependency.print_to_console(msg);
    };
};

init_worker();
```

I have a basic html file that import index.js (After compiling from typescript)

**index.html**

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="./index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now how do I import **dependency.ts** into both **index.ts** and **worker.ts**?

I have tried:
`import * as dependency from './dependency';` but the compiler gives me the error `error TS2306: File 'C:/Users/Austin/Documents/test_typescript/dependency.ts' is not a module.`

I also tried `/// <reference path="dependency.ts" >` but unfortunately this didn't seem to  do anything at all.

I'm new to typescript, and come from a mostly python background, so perhaps I'm doing something wrong or misunderstanding what typescript is capable of.

Is it possible to import from other typescript files? What is the correct way to do this for the web?

---

***EDIT:***

I've tried the following:

- added `export` before the **dependency.ts** function
- added  `type="module"` to the  tag in **index.html**
- changed the import line to `import { print_to_console } from "./dependency.js";`
- added `"module": "es6",` to tsconfig.json.

This only *partially* works.
Doing this makes index.ts successfully import the code, but the worker.ts file cannot: `SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`

Comment: The short answer is 'use a build tool like Webpack to bundle everything into a single minified file'

Comment: @NickBailey Oh okay, so this isn't possible with plain typescript?

Comment: At minimum you'd need to compile it to JavaScript first. Typescript isn't supported natively in the browser.

Comment: @NickBailey It is being compiled, yes, but the compiled javascript cannot see the imports.

Comment: Oh gotcha, sorry misunderstood. On mobile so hopefully someone gives you a fuller explanation but yes it's possible, but the 'standard' solution is to use a bundler.

Answer (score 0):

you have to `export` something in a file (or `module.exports`, but `export` is typical in typescript) for it to be a module

e.g.

```
export function print_to_console(msg:string) {
    console.log(msg);
}
```

you'll have to export any content you want to access elsewhere.

and then when you want to use `print_to_console` you can

```
import {print_to_console} from './dependency';
//import * as dependency from './dependency'; //alternatively
```

[here's the ts docs on the topic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/modules.html)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The browser spits out: `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined <anonymous> http://localhost:13002/index.js:2`

Comment: `Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });`
Being the (compiled) line it refers to.

Comment: I looked up that error and it turns out you need to add `.js` to the end of the import, change the script tag in the html to type="module", and some config stuff.  (Added more information in the edit on the main question.)

My web worker still won't import it, but at least it's partially functional.